# Angular - multiple ng repeat in table

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

*[EDIT : Solved but i think there's a better way, if you find it, i'm still interested]*

I have a list of banks.
Each bank contains a list of accounts.
Each accounts contains a list of operations.

I would like to display all the operations in a table.

Here's what the bank list looks like :

```
$scope.banks = [
    {
        id: 1,
        name: 'bank_1',
        accounts: [
            {
                id: 1,
                name: 'account_1',
                operations: [
                    {id: 1, name:'operation_1', price:100},
                    {id: 2, name:'operation_2', price:200},
                    {id: 3, name:'operation_3', price:300},
                    {id: 4, name:'operation_4', price:400}
                ]
            },
            {
                id: 2,
                name: 'account_2',
                operations: [
                    {id: 5, name:'operation_5', price:100},
                    {id: 6, name:'operation_6', price:200},
                    {id: 7, name:'operation_7', price:300},
                    {id: 8, name:'operation_8', price:400}
                ]
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        id: 2,
        name: 'bank_2',
        accounts: [
            {
                id: 3,
                name: 'account_3',
                operations: [
                    {id: 9, name:'operation_9', price:100},
                    {id: 10, name:'operation_10', price:200},
                    {id: 11, name:'operation_11', price:300},
                    {id: 12, name:'operation_12', price:400}
                ]
            },
            {
                id: 4,
                name: 'account_4',
                operations: [
                    {id: 13, name:'operation_13', price:100},
                    {id: 14, name:'operation_14', price:200},
                    {id: 15, name:'operation_15', price:300},
                    {id: 16, name:'operation_16', price:400}
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
];
```

In order to display that properly with Angular i wanted to make something like that :

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>Banque</th>
        <th>Account</th>
        <th>ID OP</th>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Price</th>
    </tr>

    <div ng-repeat="bank in banks">
        <div ng-repeat="account in bank.accounts">
            <div ng-repeat="operation in account.operations">
                <tr>
                    <td>{{banque.name}}</td>
                    <td>{{account.name}}</td>
                    <td>{{operation.id}}</td>
                    <td>{{operation.name}}</td>
                    <td>{{operation.price}}</td>
                </tr>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

</table>
```

But i know it's not correct to break the table > tr > td.

After some researches, i think i may have to use the ng-repeat-start, ng-repeat-end directive but i don't understand how and i'm not even sure it's the good thing to do.

If you have any idea how to solve that i'd be glad to hear your solution.

Comment: you can easily use <div> structure instead of table structure.

Comment: Sure, i could. But it won't be aligned like a table. At the end, i may use div if there are no solutions to this problem ... But besides this fact, i'm really curious and i would like to know how to solve that problem :)

Comment: I find your approach better but would like to suggest to keep <div> tags inside <td> and you can apply ng-repeat on <tr> and <tbody>. You can have multiple tbody inside a table.

Comment: I think pankajparkar's solution is good. But i would like to avoid using a filter. This app may have a lot of operations and i don't think filter will help. 
Maybe it's a limitation to angular ... Maybe there's no way to do exactly what i want. Your idea is nice, but cover only 2 ng-repeat, one on tbody, the other on tr. I have 3 ng-repeat (and no i cannot use it on tr, it makes no sense at all).

Comment: Yes correct. No meaning of filtering data by loops. I am not sure Why you think div will not work. There is no table structure that can not be achieved using div. I have added dynamic number of repeaters in my project. There is no limitations on number of repeaters there. All you need to put the css appropriately.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This can be easily achieved by creating custom filter that will return the list of operation.

**Filter**

```
.filter('filterData', function(){
  return function(data, firstParam, secondParam){
    var returnData = [];
    angular.forEach(data, function(value, index){
      angular.forEach(value[firstParam], function(val, ind){
        angular.forEach(val[secondParam], function(v, i){
          returnData.push(v)
        });
      });
    });
    return returnData;
  }
});
```

**Markup**

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>ID</th>
    <th>Name</th>
    <th>Price</th>
  </tr>
  <tr ng-repeat="operation in banks| filterData: 'accounts': 'operations'">
    <td>{{operation.id}}</td>
    <td>{{operation.name}}</td>
    <td>{{operation.price}}</td>
  </tr>

</table>
```

[**Working Plunkr**](http://plnkr.co/edit/itPq5wKDrst7kbYoyUgy?p=preview) Here

Hope this could help you, Thanks.

Comment: Your answer sounds promising ! But i forgot in my example to write that i also need to access to bank object and account object. Is it possible with your code ? I'm not sure (i'm going to edit my post).

Comment: yes, you need to push the required element inside `returnData` of filter

Answer (score 0):

Thx you saved my day.

I enhance your solution because filterData function is running twice (for each element of $scope.banks array).

Prefers ng-init in tbody container of tr_ngrepeat.

```
<table>
 <thead>
   <tr>
    <th>ID</th>
    <th>Name</th>
    <th>Price</th>
  </tr>
 </thead>
 <tbody ng-init="operationlist=(banks|filterData: 'accounts': 'operations')">
  <tr ng-repeat="operation in operationlist">
    <td>{{operation.id}}</td>
    <td>{{operation.name}}</td>
    <td>{{operation.price}}</td>
  </tr>
 </tbody>
</table>
```