# Multiple Nested ng-repeat-start fails to display data

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I am trying to flatten out a nested json object & display it in a table.

So I tried using multiple ng-repeat-start & ng-repeat-end elements in a div.
But somehow data is not getting displayed.

Plunkr : 
http://plnkr.co/edit/apuf9YUYnkoSaCDaNYrC?p=preview

**HTML :**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="plunker">

  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>AngularJS Plunker</title>
    <script>document.write('<base href="' + document.location + '" />');</script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script data-require="angular.js@1.2.x" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.2.22/angular.js" data-semver="1.2.22"></script>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body ng-controller="MainCtrl">

    Data is  : 
    {{mydata}}

    <table cellspacing="1" border="1">
      <thead>
        <tr> 
        <td> MainTitle</td>
        <td> SubTitle</td>
        <td> LastTitle</td>
        <td> Final</td>
        </tr>

      </thead>
      <tbody>
      <div ng-repeat-start="main in mydata" ng-if="false"></div>    
      <div ng-repeat-start="sub in main.items" ng-if="false"></div>    
      <div ng-repeat-start="last in sub.l2items" ng-if="false"></div>


      <tr ng-repeat="final in last.l3items">
        <td> {{main.title}} </td>
        <td> {{sub.title}} </td>
        <td> {{last.title}} </td>
        <td> {{final}} </td>

      </tr>
      </tbody>
      <div ng-repeat-end ng-if="false"></div>    
      <div ng-repeat-end ng-if="false"></div>    
      <div ng-repeat-end ng-if="false"></div>

    </table>
  </body>

</html>
```

**Code:**

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.name = 'World';



    $scope.mydata = [
      {
        title :"hello",
        items : [
          {
          title: "level 1 title",
          l2items : [
            {
            title : "level 2 title",
            l3items: [ "a","b" ]

           }
            ]
        }
        ,
         {
          title: "level 1 title 1 ",
          l2items : [
            {
            title : "level 2 title 1",
            l3items: [ "a 1","b 1" ]
           }
            ]
        }
      ]
      },{
      title :"hello 0",
        items : [
          {
          title: "level 1 title 0",
          l2items : [
            {
            title : "level 2 title 0",
            l3items: [ "a 0","b 0" ]

           }
            ]
        }
        ,
         {
          title: "level 1 title 1 0",
          l2items : [
            {
            title : "level 2 title 1 0",
            l3items: [ "a 1 0","b 1 0" ]
           }
            ]
        }
      ],
      }]
});
```

**Expected Output :** (apologies could not create a proper table)

Main title  | Subtitle  | LastTitle | Final

hello       |level 1 title  |level 2 title  |a

hello   |level 1 title  |level 2 title  |b

hello   |level 1 title 1    |level 2 title 1    |a 1

hello   |level 1 title 1    |level 2 title 1    |b 1

hello 0 |level 1 title 0    |level 2 title 0    |a 0

hello 0 |level 1 title 0    |level 2 title 0    |b 0

hello 0 |level 1 title 1 0  |level 2 title 1 0  |a 1 0

hello 0 |level 1 title 1 0  |level 2 title 1 0  b 1 0

Comment: If you want that in a table why don't you just map to a flattened  array before you pass it to the view?

Comment: You can try to use <ng-repeat ng-repeat="repeat_expression"> element to remove the extra <div> tags

Comment: @JoaozitoPolo I experimented with that and it wasn't working still.  http://plnkr.co/edit/DtcGibbB09v3sS13B9k3?p=preview

Comment: @charlietfl flattening was my last option coz array is 6 level deep . Hence thought to manage it directly via angular.

Comment: That will be very expensive nesting that many repeats when what you want is a flat display. You will pay a significant performance penalty vs flattening the data first

Comment: @charlietfl will definitely compare both for my use now.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I believe the problem is with your HTML.  Most likely having divs inside your table.  If you convert it to `<div>`s then it works.  Another issue I saw was that you were repeating your closing `</body>` tag.

I understand why you were doing it with the `<div>`s and `ng-if`s.  There was, at one time, a comment directive version of the `ng-repeat`, or at least an effort to create one, but I think they ran into [browser limitations](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/pull/1646#issuecomment-21039443).

Here is a [similar issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29074747/angular-multiple-ng-repeat-in-table).  Perhaps you'll like their solution.

Otherwise, replace your `<div>`s with `<tr>`s:

```
  <tr ng-repeat-start="main in mydata" ng-if="false"></tr>
  <tr ng-repeat-start="sub in main.items" ng-if="false"></tr>
  <tr ng-repeat-start="last in sub.l2items" ng-if="false"></tr>

  <tr ng-repeat="final in last.l3items">
    <td> {{main.title}} </td>
    <td> {{sub.title}} </td>
    <td> {{last.title}} </td>
    <td> {{final}} </td>

  </tr>

  <tr ng-repeat-end ng-if="false"></tr>
  <tr ng-repeat-end ng-if="false"></tr>
  <tr ng-repeat-end ng-if="false"></tr>
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/jPtHDbaonUtc9tXQadc2?p=preview